# Laravel websockets `Failed to connect to Pusher.`

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, pusher, broadcasting

I have the following problem with my websocket setup on local:
Once an event arrives at the backend, I want to trigger another event from the backend side.
But for some reason, the websocket terminal is telling me, that the connection to pusher failed. and after that message, the event i want to trigger is fired anyway.
my Question: What is causing the connection error?

Setup:
.env:

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=1234
PUSHER_APP_KEY=ABCDEFG
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=HIJKLMNOP
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

websockets.php:

```
    'apps' => [
    [
        'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'capacity' => null,
        'enable_client_messages' => false,
        'enable_statistics' => true,
    ],
],
```

broadcasting.php:

```
        'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            //'useTLS' => true,
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => 6001,
            'scheme' => 'http',
            'timeout' => 1
        ],
    ],
```

Versions:

```
"php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "beyondcode/laravel-websockets": "1.12",
    "fideloper/proxy": "4.4",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.54",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "laravel/ui": "^3.1",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0",
    "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^4.0"
```

I dont get what is trying to connect and why is the event fired after the timeout?

Regards

Answer (score -1):

on local change to `'useTLS' => false,`

It should be like the following

```
'connections' => [
    'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            'useTLS' => false,
        ],
    ],
    ....
```

Comment: Tried that, but it doesn’t helped :(